# Error:(26) error: unknown element <intent-filter> found

Tags: android

I have a strange error and I can not handle it. And why all the lines have a strange error? 
It started suddenly, why did this happen?

this my Manifast:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="budgetreport.com.budgetreport"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:testOnly="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="budgetreport.com.budgetreport.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.1.0" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
        android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
        android:authorities="budgetreport.com.budgetreport.com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
        android:multiprocess="true" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

This The Error:[image]

And why all the lines have a strange error?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to let `MainActivity` as a lanuch ,you should add this to the `Activity` tag .It did not use in the `application` tag directly .

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Try this in your code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="budgetreport.com.budgetreport"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:testOnly="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="budgetreport.com.budgetreport.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.1.0"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
        android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT"/>

    <provider
        android:name="com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
        android:authorities="budgetreport.com.budgetreport.com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
        android:multiprocess="true"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this block :

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This block should be inserted between `<activity>` and `</activity>` of your `MainActivity` TAG

Comment: I don't understand where that? @dany poplawec